# Objective-C Memory Management: Am I understanding this?

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

I've finally decided to stop beating around the bush and teach myself some Objective-C. It's all making sense, except when I get to the memory management and this idea of the "autorelease pool".
From my understanding, if I specifically create an object using init,new, alloc or tell it to retain, then it is my job to deallocate the memory. However, an autorelease pool will automatically free up any objects associated with the innermost autorelease pool?
For example, say I do this:

```
TestOBJ* foo = [[[TestOBJ alloc] innit] autorelease];
```

Then it will be released at the end of the first @autoreleasepool block, or whenever the first [autoreleasepool drain] is called?

Also; just because an object is created within an autoreleasepool block doesn't mean it is automatically labeled as autorelease, correct?

Comment: Small correction: You say "it is my job to deallocate the memory." It is your job to *release* the memory. Whether this results in it being deallocated or not is a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct for both points.

Objects only get added to autorelease pools if you call `-autorelease` on them. By convention all methods *not* starting with `alloc`, `new`, `copy` or `mutableCopy` return objects that they have themselves added to the autorelease pool, so you don't have to do it yourself.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html for details.

Comment: To be clear, though, the frameworks will often return autoreleased objects.   I.e. `NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"..."];` will return an autoreleased object.

Comment: @CodaFi: There *is* a `constructor` attribute, but that is not what it does at all. You're thinking of the family of attributes along the lines of `ns_returns_retained` and `ns_returns_not_retained`.

Comment: "By convention all methods not starting with ... return objects that they have themselves added to the autorelease pool" Not true. They simply return objects that you do not own. There is no guarantee that they belong to an autorelease pool.

Comment: @Chuck My god, why did I post that?  I meant `__attribute__((objc_method_family( init )))`

Comment: @newacct Good point ! I had taken the habit of always ensuring objects I return are in the autorelease pool but you may encounter cases where this is not true (container classes like `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` come to mind). This is getting less of a problem with ARC though, since local variables capture objects strongly anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much answered all your questions yourself correctly.